# Being at the same scroll position after display a popup

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, popup

I have a classic page with a lot of content, and a button that open a popup.
This pop can have an height bigger than my window, so i need to scroll inside my pop up.
When I hide my trigger, i want to be on the exact same scroll position than before showing this pop up.
I have try many solution, and... it's not exactly that :)
You can see an example on JSfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/S6EFW/

And you can see what i'm trying to do on the site of USA TODAY : http://www.usatoday.com/

If you scroll a bit, and click on one of the main article, a popup shows. You can scroll in this popup. When you close the popup, you're on the exact same place of the page than befor opening the popup.

My code :

```
  $( "#launch" ).click(function() {
  $( "#popup" ).fadeToggle( "slow", function() {

  });
    $( "#content" ).toggleClass( "whenloaded" );

  });
```

With a class added on the content when you show the popup :

```
 .whenloaded {
  position : fixed;
 }
```

If you have an idea to the way to achieve that ! Many thanks to the community :)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm right, [this will be close to what you are after](http://jsfiddle.net/S6EFW/3/)

**Edit: [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S6EFW/8/)**

The relevant CSS:

```
html,body{ 
   margin:0; padding:0; height:100%; width:100%; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; overflow:hidden; 
}
#content{
    overflow-y:scroll;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
#launch{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:999;
    background:white;
    padding:4px;
    border:1px solid grey;
}
#overlay{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display:none;
    z-index:99;
    text-align:center;
}
#mask{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:blue;
    opacity:0.5;
}
#popup{
    z-index:100;
    position:relative;
    width:60%;
    top:20%;
    margin:auto;
    max-height:100px; 
    background:white;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but i dont want a separate scroll in the page and in the popup. I try to have exactly the same result as USA today, with a unique scroll. But thank you !!

Comment: Thanks, that's a very interesting solution ! But i'm force to have a content div in absolute position ? No way to keep a relative position ?

Comment: Sure, change the body css to: html,body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;   
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

Comment: thanks, you're awesome :) I still have a problem, if i have any absolute div on content, the scroll bar appears under this element. See here : http://jsfiddle.net/S6EFW/10/

Comment: Simply add 'position:relative;' to your #content so that any absolutely positioned elements use the #content element for their relevance calculations

Comment: yes, but if I do that, the menu header is not fixed anymore. And if I add a position : fixed to the menu, I have the same problem, the scroll bar goes under the menu. :(

Comment: You might want to split that out into a new question so you get more traffic / answers

Comment: Thanks :) I will try to fix it, and ask a new question if necessary. Many many thanks for your help !!

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out what you mean. If you want to have a static page (no inputs and stuff), a simpler way would be to use plain javascript. Using innerHtml, and css you can put all your content in a div and give it 2 different IDs depending on whether the pop-up is opened or not, and 1 id has the css show nothing. For the state where the pop-up is opened, use z-index and y-overflow.

I will edit this later and post an example if I get the opportunity.